# Laravel max Validator not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel.

Could someone explain why `max` validator doesn't work as I expected in this case?

```
$input = ["schoolSeatsTotal" => '2000'];
$rules = ['schoolSeatsTotal'=>'max:300'];
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
$validator->fails(); //Expected: true, Actual: false.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have `schoolSeatsTotal` as a string. For string data, max value corresponds to the number of characters. You want to validate an integer instead.

So change

```
$input = ["schoolSeatsTotal" => '2000'];
```

to

```
$input = ["schoolSeatsTotal" => 2000];
```

To make sure you are validating numbers - do this:

```
$rules = ['schoolSeatsTotal'=>'numeric|max:300'];
```

Comment: The `['schoolSeatsTotal'=>'numeric|max:300'];` fixed it, not the $input change. Thanks!

Comment: the comment is true!

Comment: btw: numeric also works with strings ('2000'). So the right answer is make a rule just 'numeric|max:300'